Create Kedro PartitionedDataset of PartitionedDatasets
I'm working in a kedro project where I want to automatically label thousands of audio files, apply transformations to them and then store them in a folder of folders, each subfolder corresponding to one label. I want that folder of folders to be a catalog entry  on my yml file
I followed this Kedro tutorial and created my own custom dataset for saving/loading .wav files in kedro catalog. I also am able to create PartitionedDataset  catalog entries in catalog.yml such as
audio_folder:
  type: partitions.PartitionedDataset
  dataset: my_kedro_project.datasets.audio_dataset.SoundDataset
  path: data/output/audios/
  filename_suffix: ".WAV"

for saving/loading folders of .WAV files in Kedro catalog.
The next level of abstraction I would require is to be able to create a catalog entry corresponding to a folder containig folders such as the audio_folder above. I don't want to do this by dynamicaly creating catalog entries but by extending PartitionedDataset class. This is because I want the folder of folders to be part of my catalog.yml. My questions are

Is this possible? Has any of you ever try something like this?
In case it is possible, my custom class should only include the _load, _save, and _describe methods as when I'm customizing an AbstractDataset?

EDIT
I finally decided to create annother custom class extending AbstractDataset. Here are some details about the _load and _save methods:
def _load(self):
        subfolder_names=[ subfolder_name 
                         for subfolder_name in os.listdir(self._mainfolderpath) 
                         if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(self._mainfolderpath, subfolder_name)) 
                        ]
        
        
        wav_paths_dict={}
        for subfolder_name in subfolder_names:
            subfolder_path=os.path.join(self._mainfolderpath, subfolder_name)
            wav_files=[]
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(subfolder_path):
                for file in files:
                    if file.lower().endswith('.wav'):
                        wav_file_path=os.path.join(root, file)
                        wav_file_name=os.path.split(wav_file_path)[-1].replace('.wav','').replace('.WAV','')
                        wav_files.append((wav_file_name,wav_file_path))
                wav_paths_dict[subfolder_name]=dict(wav_files)

        
        partitioned_dataset_dict={}
        for subfolder_name, sub_dict in wav_paths_dict.items():
            partitioned_dataset=[(wav_file_name,SoundDataset(wav_file_path).load()) for wav_file_name,wav_file_path in sub_dict.items()]
            partitioned_dataset_dict[subfolder_name]=dict(partitioned_dataset)
        
        return partitioned_dataset_dict

And
def _save(self, subfolders_dictionary):
        if os.path.isdir(self._mainfolderpath):
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self._mainfolderpath,topdown=False):
                for name in files:
                    os.remove(os.path.join(root, name))
                for name in dirs:
                    os.rmdir(os.path.join(root, name))
            os.rmdir(self._mainfolderpath)
        os.mkdir(self._mainfolderpath)
        for subfolder_name in subfolders_dictionary.keys():
            subfolder_path=os.path.join(self._mainfolderpath, subfolder_name) 
            os.mkdir(os.path.normpath(subfolder_path))

            #print(subfolder_name, subfolder_path)
            partitioned_dataset = PartitionedDataset(
            path=subfolder_path,
            dataset=SoundDataset,
            filename_suffix=".WAV",
            )
            
            partitioned_dataset.save(subfolders_dictionary[subfolder_name])


What is consider a single dataset here in your example? Is it one folder of audio files or a single of them? By default PartitionedDataset scan a single folder, but you can pass arguments to the load_args to iterate on multiple folder. Ofcourse you can also inherit the class and customise the way it iterates.
Link: https://docs.kedro.org/projects/kedro-datasets/en/kedro-datasets-4.1.0/api/kedro_datasets.partitions.PartitionedDataset.html
p.s. you can find fsspec document to see what arguments are allow for the find method, it takes something like regex so it could be enough for you

I removed the "computer vision" tag. what was supposed to be "computer vision" about this question? it's dealing with audio.

@mediumnok what I consider a "single dataset" is partitions.PartitionedDataset of SoundDatasets i.e. what I consider a "single dataset" is a folder of audio files

@ChristophRackwitz the folder structure I want and the kind of pipeline I described is common in CV. Thought someone in CV community might have donde what I want to do or might benefit from a satisfactory answer
